# Dividing cell with sum of every nth cell in same column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame( Country = c("AL","AL","AL","AL","FR","FR","FR","FR","UK","UK","UK","UK"),
                          LT5F   = c(4,2,1,3,2,1,4,1,2,1,2,2),
                          LT5M   = c(5,3,4,2,2,1,0,7,3,2,1,0),
                          LT5T   = c(9,5,5,5,4,2,4,8,5,3,3,2),
                          Y9t14F = c(3,2,1,3,5,3,7,4,3,3,2,5),
                          Y9t14M = c(1,5,3,2,4,6,1,5,3,4,4,3),
                          Y9t14T = c(4,7,4,5,9,9,8,9,6,7,6,8))
```

I wish to **sum every nth observation (1100 in my real data) and divide each number in that 1100 range with the sum**. In my example n = 4. The sum of every column every 4th observation is:

```
 Sum4thObs <- data.frame( L
                      LT5F   = c(10,8,7),
                      LT5M   = c(14,10,6),
                      LT5T   = c(24,18,13),
                      Y9t14F = c(9,19,13),
                      Y9t14M = c(11,16,14),
                      Y9t14T = c(20,35,27))
```

What I want is a dataframe where every cell is divided by the sum of the range which is "n"-long.

My dream dataframe looks like this:

```
dfdream <- data.frame( Country = c("AL","AL","AL","AL","FR","FR","FR","FR","UK","UK","UK","UK"),
                     LT5F   = c(4/10,2/10,1/10,3/10,2/8,1/8,4/8,1/8,2/7,1/7,2/7,2/7),
                     LT5M   = c(5/14,3/14,4/14,2/14,2/10,1/10,0/10,7/10,3/6,2/6,1/6,0/6),
                     LT5T   = c(),
                     Y9t14F = c(),
                     Y9t14M = c(),
                     Y9t14T = c())
```

and so on...

Also I have fifty columns with 100 unique country identifiers (AL, FR, UK = 3 in the example). Is there a smart and easy way for me to divide every cell by its 1:1100 sum?

I hope my question was clear. Thank you.

Comment: In your sample data, you have four rows for each `Country`.  Do you want to calculate your divisors based on `Country` or row count regardless of `Country`?

Comment: Row. But I dont know if it matters, in my data set every country is always 1100 Rows. Some of the values in that 1100 range are NA however so one country might only have data in 500 of 1100 columns. In that case I could like to sum the 500 observations and divide with that number. Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your "dream dataframe" by :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(across(LT5F:Y9t14T, prop.table)) %>%
  ungroup

#  Country  LT5F  LT5M  LT5T Y9t14F Y9t14M Y9t14T
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 AL      0.4   0.357 0.375  0.333 0.0909  0.2  
# 2 AL      0.2   0.214 0.208  0.222 0.455   0.35 
# 3 AL      0.1   0.286 0.208  0.111 0.273   0.2  
# 4 AL      0.3   0.143 0.208  0.333 0.182   0.25 
# 5 FR      0.25  0.2   0.222  0.263 0.25    0.257
# 6 FR      0.125 0.1   0.111  0.158 0.375   0.257
# 7 FR      0.5   0     0.222  0.368 0.0625  0.229
# 8 FR      0.125 0.7   0.444  0.211 0.312   0.257
# 9 UK      0.286 0.5   0.385  0.231 0.214   0.222
#10 UK      0.143 0.333 0.231  0.231 0.286   0.259
#11 UK      0.286 0.167 0.231  0.154 0.286   0.222
#12 UK      0.286 0     0.154  0.385 0.214   0.296
```

If you have `NA`'s you can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(across(LT5F:Y9t14T, ~./sum(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple base solution:

assuming `df` is your example dataset

```
i <- 1:12
li <- split(i, cut(i, 3, labels = FALSE))

 myfun <- function(i){
  a <- df[i,-1]
  b <- colSums(df[i,-1])
  result <- mapply("/",a,b)
  return(result)
}
dfdream <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(li,myfun)))
dfdream$County <- df$Country
```

now it works:

```
dfdream
        LT5F      LT5M      LT5T    Y9t14F     Y9t14M    Y9t14T County
1  0.4000000 0.3571429 0.3750000 0.3333333 0.09090909 0.2000000     AL
2  0.2000000 0.2142857 0.2083333 0.2222222 0.45454545 0.3500000     AL
3  0.1000000 0.2857143 0.2083333 0.1111111 0.27272727 0.2000000     AL
4  0.3000000 0.1428571 0.2083333 0.3333333 0.18181818 0.2500000     AL
5  0.2500000 0.2000000 0.2222222 0.2631579 0.25000000 0.2571429     FR
6  0.1250000 0.1000000 0.1111111 0.1578947 0.37500000 0.2571429     FR
7  0.5000000 0.0000000 0.2222222 0.3684211 0.06250000 0.2285714     FR
8  0.1250000 0.7000000 0.4444444 0.2105263 0.31250000 0.2571429     FR
9  0.2857143 0.5000000 0.3846154 0.2307692 0.21428571 0.2222222     UK
10 0.1428571 0.3333333 0.2307692 0.2307692 0.28571429 0.2592593     UK
11 0.2857143 0.1666667 0.2307692 0.1538462 0.28571429 0.2222222     UK
12 0.2857143 0.0000000 0.1538462 0.3846154 0.21428571 0.2962963     UK
```

Comment: In the Column LT5F the third cell should be 1/10 but I can see that this value is 0.0416667. But it should be 1. So something might need to be tweaked?

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` solution to get the proportion by country:

```
library(data.table)

dtPropByCountry <- setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x/sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)),
                             by = Country, .SDcols = 2:ncol(df)]
```